# How to apply searching on an array elements?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am implementing search bar in my iphone app to apply searching on array element.
In that array I save the data fetched from server through parsing.
The data contains some links for pdf files like this: myArray is an mutable array and its elements are :

```
http://www.projects-demo.com/iphone/unicurd/recipePagePdf/abc.pdf
http://www.projects-demo.com/iphone/unicurd/recipePagePdf/def.pdf
http://www.projects-demo.com/iphone/unicurd/recipePagePdf/ghi.pdf
http://www.projects-demo.com/iphone/unicurd/recipePagePdf/jkl.pdf
http://www.projects-demo.com/iphone/unicurd/recipePagePdf/mno.pdf
http://www.projects-demo.com/iphone/unicurd/recipePagePdf/pqr.pdf
http://www.projects-demo.com/iphone/unicurd/recipePagePdf/stu.pdf
http://www.projects-demo.com/iphone/unicurd/recipePagePdf/vwx.pdf
http://www.projects-demo.com/iphone/unicurd/recipePagePdf/yz1.pdf
```

I am saving the string to be searched in searchtext.text
Now what logic should be implement for searching this searchtext.text in myArray's element ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new array that holds the value if foundlet it be copyitemcity.

Searching code:-

```
NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;

for (NSString *str in folderCheckArray)
    {

NSRange titleResultsRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if(titleResultsRange.location != NSNotFound)

        {

        if (titleResultsRange.location==0)
        {
            [copyitemcity addObject:str];
        }
        }


}
```

Try this code for searching.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:-
let name of your array folderCheckArray(change by yours).

in your search bar searchBUttonclick method:-

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar
{
if ([self.folderCheckArray containsObject:theSearchBar.text]) {
    NSLog(@"array contain object"); 
    }
else
{
NSLog(@"array contain object"); 
}
}
```

if you have to do any formatting in the search text before searching it in array you can then write

```
if([self.folderCheckArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theSearchBar.text]]) {
}
```

Comment: @Jennifer: Thanks a lot!!! but in this way in theSearchBar.text we have to enter string same to same as array element. But according to searching logic theSearchBar.text can be any substring of array element.

Comment: @archana if you are using the searching logic then when you enter the string might ge a substring you should get the whole value of your array element if the search string exist in any of your array value. you need to check your  searching code,You will get your solution in it

Comment: @Jennifer:Definitely it will be substring because the array contains the URL fetched from server and the end user will not know/enter the whole URL to search. And I want that logic only that how a string will compare as a substring with array element. Can u plz explain this line if([self.folderCheckArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theSearchBar.text]]) {
} means what type of formatting in the search text before searching it in array I can do, may be this will help me out. Thanks

Comment: @archana I dont think if([self.folderCheckArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theSearchBar.text]]) this will work for you because it requires the whole stringmeans the object that an array contains but are entering a substring for that you can follow my second answer ,i am sure it will help you.